# Панельная регрессия в python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, статистика, статический-анализ

Подскажите, как реализовать панельную регрессию в питоне с фиксированным эффектом (fixed effect). Никак не могу разобраться с функцией PanelOLS
Итак,  панель строится по двум показателям: регион и год, и даны 6 переменных

```
             Region  Year    x1   x2   x3    x4        x5     x6
0    Алтайский край  2008   8.0  3.4  0.3  52.2  2.211530  0.380
1    Алтайский край  2009   8.3  3.7  0.3  50.4  1.929982  0.360
2    Алтайский край  2010   9.8  4.1  0.4  59.1  1.878556  0.362
3    Алтайский край  2011  10.8  4.5  0.4  63.4  2.103315  0.368
4    Алтайский край  2012  11.0  4.8  0.4  70.4  2.178200  0.375
5  Амурская область  2008  13.4  6.3  0.4  69.1  2.161920  0.373
6  Амурская область  2009  10.2  6.7  0.5  73.0  2.061231  0.367
7  Амурская область  2010  11.6  7.6  0.6  76.0  1.999581  0.427
8  Амурская область  2011  12.0  7.2  0.6  83.3  2.237736  0.376
9  Амурская область  2012  13.3  5.8  0.6  75.8  2.565301  0.390
```

Как построить регрессию? Для примере сделайте `x1 ~ x2+x3`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [74]: from linearmodels import PanelOLS

In [75]: mod = PanelOLS.from_formula('x1 ~ x2 + x3', df.set_index('Year', append=True))

In [76]: mod.fit(cov_type='clustered', cluster_entity=True)
...
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

PS почему возникает `ZeroDivisionError` я не знаю - надо смотреть формулы и разбираться

---

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

model = smf.ols(formula='x1 ~ x2 + x3', data=df)
res = model.fit()
print(res.summary())
```

Результат:

```
                            OLS Regression Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                     x1   R-squared:                       0.520
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.383
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     3.793
Date:                Sat, 19 Jan 2019   Prob (F-statistic):             0.0766
Time:                        21:54:53   Log-Likelihood:                -16.105
No. Observations:                  10   AIC:                             38.21
Df Residuals:                       7   BIC:                             39.12
Df Model:                           2
Covariance Type:            nonrobust
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept      5.7522      1.920      2.996      0.020       1.212      10.293
x2             0.4952      0.625      0.792      0.454      -0.983       1.973
x3             5.3533      8.002      0.669      0.525     -13.569      24.276
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        1.107   Durbin-Watson:                   1.635
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.575   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.847
Skew:                           0.581   Prob(JB):                        0.655
Kurtosis:                       2.174   Cond. No.                         100.
==============================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

Comment: По-моему это обычная регрессия, а не панельная

Comment: @Max52, добавил панельную с мультииндексом по `Year`, но вываливается `ZeroDivisionError` при обучении.