# Как получить доступ к значению из ответа python

Tags: python, pandas

При условиях этой задачи
[Панельная регрессия в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933785/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-python/934214#934214)

Например, как мне выцепить какое-то определенное значение из саммари?

Допустим я хочу получить на выход значение-коэффициент `x3`, то есть в условиях данной задачи `5.3533`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import io
import pandas as pd


In [39]: d = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(res.summary().tables[1].as_csv()),
                         index_col=0, sep='\s*,\s*', engine='python')

In [40]: d
Out[40]:
             coef  std err      t  P>|t|  [0.025  0.975]
Intercept  5.7522    1.920  2.996  0.020   1.212  10.293
x2         0.4952    0.625  0.792  0.454  -0.983   1.973
x3         5.3533    8.002  0.669  0.525 -13.569  24.276

In [41]: d.loc['x3', 'coef']
Out[41]: 5.3533
```